# Configure PHPMailer with Amazon SES dedicated IP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, phpmailer

I have an dedicated IP address on Amazon SES but I don't know how to find these informations I use for Amazon shared IP I put in my PHP file:

```
$configEmail['Host'] = 'email-smtp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com';
$configEmail['SMTPAuth'] = TRUE;
$configEmail['Username'] = 'AKIAW7D...';
$configEmail['Password'] = 'BFFuNfJO...';
$configEmail['Port'] = 587;
$configEmail['SMTPSecure'] = 'tls';
```

[image]

I do have a new user since I created this dedicated IP address and I have found the Access key of this new user in the menu "Identity and Access Management -> IAM > Users" but no password anywhere found and no host as well found.

Where to find these information?